# How to display a result in the other activity?

Tags: java, android

```
String[] items =  {"Yes","No"};

@Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Item: "+item,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
```

How to display a result in next activity?
I want to make a drop-down and if I choose yes, a result must show when I press confirm.

Comment: It depends.  It might as simple as declaring a field (a variable) in the enclosing class and assigning `item` to it.  I recommend that you find / read a tutorial on writing Android apps.

Comment: I am trying to fin a way to store this value of yes, then it must show some result in the next activity.

Comment: So ... explain clearly what you are trying to do **in the question**.  Use the **edit** button.

Comment: But I suspect that this is just a duplicate of (for example) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not being able to edit it one more time... Can you give me a hint so I can google more? I did a dropdown menu asking a question, what I'm trying to do is when I choose yes, a specific answer shows in the next activity.

Comment: Why are you not able to edit it?  Can't you find the edit link???  See the line of tags?  See the line under that?  See the grey "Edit" ?

Comment: It only show me this!

Approve, reject, or improve this suggested edit.

Comment: Sir in my case I would like to to ask a question and have a dropmenu with yes or no. If I choose yes then a result show in other activity. Can you give me a hint on what to google? Thank you!

Comment: Should I declare that yes is equal to something?
I want to show the result that comes from the answer yes.

Comment: Maybe.  I'm not understanding what you are saying.  I think you would be better off reading a tutorial on Java programming and another on writing Android apps in Java.  StackOverflow is NOT a tutoring / teaching service.

Comment: Im sorry for being kind of ignorant... WHat I meant is, there is a dropdown and has question like what is the month you born? If the user choose January then a result comes in the next activity like you are capricorn. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Try the answers in the link in Stephen's comment. That's how you pass data. Otherwise, add more info to the question.

Comment: Thank you I edited, hopefuly it comes with an answer :)